# OAuth 2.0 inconsistent errors when using BigQuery commandline tool

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm using BigQuery's command-line tool to load data into BigQuery.

I'm running the bq tool through a C# program using the following method:

```
    private void RunShellCmd(string cmd, string args)
    {
        ProcessStartInfo start = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = cmd,
            Arguments = args,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true
        };

        using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
            {
                string result = reader.ReadToEnd();

                if (OnMessage != null)
                {
                    OnMessage(result);                        
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Where **cmd** is the path for the bq script tool and **args** are:
load --nosync --credential_file=_CRED_PATH_ --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON  --project_id=_PROJECT_ID_ _TABLE_URI_ _DATA_FILE_

When performing the exact command from shell, it works perfectly.
However, through the C# program, I'm getting the following output:

```
Welcome to BigQuery! This script will walk you through the  process of initializing your .bigqueryrc configuration file.

First, we need to set up your credentials if they do not  already exist.


******************************************************************
** No OAuth2 credentials found, beginning authorization process **
******************************************************************

Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fbigquery&redirect_uri=...

Enter verification code: You have encountered a bug in the BigQuery CLI. Google engineers monitor and answer questions on Stack Overflow, with the tag google-bigquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask?tags=google-bigquery Please include a brief description of the steps that led to this issue, as well as the following information:

========================================
== Platform ==   CPython:2.7.5:Windows-2008ServerR2-6.1.7601-SP1
== bq version ==   v2.0.16
== Command line ==   ['C:\\Python27\\Scripts\\bq-script.py', 'load', '--nosync', '--credential_file=C:\\Users\\Administrator\\.bigquery.v2.token', '--source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON', '--project_id=_PROJECT_ID_',
>'_TABLE_URI_', '_DATA_FILE_PATH_']
== UTC timestamp ==   2013-10-20 05:52:59
== Error trace ==   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 783, in RunSafely
    return_value = self.RunWithArgs(*args, **kwds)   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 2082, in RunWithArgs
    client = Client.Get()   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 604, in Get
    cls.client = Client.Create()   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 584, in Create
    credentials = _GetCredentialsFromFlags()   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 390, in _GetCredentialsFromFlags
    credentials = credentials_getter(storage)   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\bq.py", line 330, in
_GetCredentialsFromOAuthFlow
    credentials = oauth2client.tools.run(flow, storage)   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\util.py", line 132, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)   File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\old_run.py", line 149, in run
    code = raw_input('Enter verification code: ').strip()
========================================

Unexpected exception in init operation: EOF when reading a line 
Successfully started load _TABLE_URI_
```

The odd thing is that the command actually works and loads the data correctly (As also proven by the final output line).
But for some reason, it is preceded by an OAUTH 2.0 error.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?
Any idea what might cause it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you calling the bq.py tool from c# rather than using the C# client?

The c# client is available here:
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/apis/#BigQuery_API
and the ndocs are here:
https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/bigquery/v2/csharp/latest/annotated.html

If you don't want to / can't use the C# client, my guess as to what is happening is that bq is having trouble writing out a credential file (or reading a credential file). Possibly this is due to a windows path issue ('/' vs '\') or possibly the path it tries to write to or read-from is inaccessible. (or possibly the path it writes to doesn't match the path it tries to read  from the next time).

Comment: Despite the C# client being in beta, I think you're probably better off using it. It says that it may change before release, but the on-the-wire API should not change in a backwards-incompatible way. So if you download the C# client now, it should continue to work until the wire api changes, which should have a 1 year+ deprecation cycle. If the C# client changes, it may require code changes, but you should have at least a year to update to the later version.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not possible at the moment. :/

After checking the suggestion you added though, I found out it's probably permissions related.
When I made the above service run as Administrator (instead of Local System Service), the issues disappeared.
It's odd though, as I added both the --credential_file flag and the --bigqueryrc flag - and pointed them to a folder with full control to everyone.

Could it be that the tool is trying to write the credentials or some other file to another folder anyway?

Comment: Ok, so apparantely, the bq tool attempts to first read the credentials from the %USERPROFILE% directory - and only afterwards (If they're invalid or don't exist) attempts to get them from the --credential_file flag.

Once I added the token to that directory, it fixed the problem.

Thanks for your help!